# Easiest way to edit/modify compiled class file

Tags: java, decompiling

My main problem is that i have some class files from a game where i wan't to edit/modify parts of it

What would be the easiest way to achieve this ?

Decompiling the whole code and recompiling is not an option unless you have some decompiler that doesn't cause errors in the source code, as i do not wish to spend time fixing them.

Best regards

Comment: Which decompilers have u used?

Comment: Are you sure you're allowed to modify the code of that game? If so, might there be a source distribution instead of having to decompile/recompile? Depending on the parts you want to change you might end up having to decompile a big portion of the game anyways.

Answer (score 7):

A solution could be the use of bytecode manipulators like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) or [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/). They both provide an API to load a class file, change part of it and save it. ASM has the advantage to be able to do this during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Krakatau disassembler/assembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) I wrote. The disassembler turns a class file into a human readable (well readable if you understand bytecode anyway) format, which you can then edit and reassemble. This is useful if you want to view and edit the classfiles by hand, where writing a bunch of library calls and then compiling and running a program just to use ASM or BCEL is rather unwieldy.

Krakatau also has a decompiler specifically designed to handle obfuscated classes, so it may be able to produce valid source code even when no other decompiler can. Of course if the class is obfuscated, the generated source will probably still be unreadable.